# Passing signals between parent and child process in C

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to use signals to pass between a parent and child process, but after the first 2 statements are printed 
for example in mine it shows:

CHILD 4225: Running, parent is 4224

PARENT 4224: Telling the Child Process 4225 to start

it just gets stuck running forever! I'm not sure where I am going wrong on this...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
void p_sig_usr(int signo){
    if(signo == SIGUSR1){
        printf("*** Parent SIGUSR1 handler - Received 'task started' signal from child        ***\n");
    }
    if(signo == SIGUSR2){
        printf("*** Parent SIGUSR2 handler - Received 'task completed' signal from child ***\n");
    }
    else
        printf("unexpected signal received");
    return;
}
void c_sig_usr(int signo){
    if(signo == SIGUSR1){
        printf("*** Child SIGUSR1 handler - Received 'task start' signal from parent ***\n");
    }
    if(signo == SIGUSR2){
        printf("*** Child SIGUSR2 handler - Received 'task complete verification' signal from parent ***\n");
    }
    else
        printf("unexpected signal received");
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t child_pid, parent_pid;
    parent_pid = getpid();
    struct sigaction p_sig;
    sigemptyset(&p_sig.sa_mask);
    p_sig.sa_flags = 0;
    p_sig.sa_handler = p_sig_usr;
    child_pid = fork();
    if ( child_pid == -1){
        perror("failed to fork a new process");
        return 1;
    }
    if (child_pid == 0){
        struct sigaction c_sig;
        sigset_t c_myset;
        sigemptyset(&c_sig.sa_mask);
        c_sig.sa_flags = 0;
        c_sig.sa_handler = c_sig_usr;
        child_pid = getpid();
        printf("CHILD %d: Running, parent is %d\n",child_pid, parent_pid);
        sigfillset(&c_myset);
        sigdelset(&c_myset, SIGUSR1);
        sigsuspend(&c_myset);//suspend until get SIGUSR1
        printf("CHILD: Telling parent that I'm starting task.\n");
        sleep(3);
        kill(parent_pid, SIGUSR1);
        printf("CHILD: Performing task\n");
        sigfillset(&c_myset);
        sigdelset(&c_myset, SIGUSR2);
        sigsuspend(&c_myset);//suspend and wait for SIGUSR2
        printf("CHILD: Telling parent that work is done.\n");
        kill(parent_pid, SIGUSR2);
        printf("CHILD %d: Finished\n", child_pid);
    }
    else{
        struct sigaction p_sig;
        sigset_t p_myset;
        sigemptyset(&p_myset);
        sleep(3);//parent now sleeping to let child set up handlers
        printf("PARENT %d: Telling the Child Process %d to start\n", parent_pid, child_pid);
        kill(child_pid, SIGUSR1);
        sigfillset(&p_myset);
        sigdelset(&p_myset, SIGUSR1);
        sigsuspend(&p_myset);//suspend until get SIGUSR1
        sleep(3);
        kill(child_pid,SIGUSR2);
        printf("PARENT: Told child to notify of task completion.\n");
        sigfillset(&p_myset);
        sigdelset(&p_myset, SIGUSR2);//suspend until get SIGUSR2
        printf("PARENT %d: Finished.", parent_pid);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just referring to the documentation for these functions—I have no experience using them.

It appears what [`sigfillset()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigfillset.html) is going to do is load the [process signal mask](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Signal-Mask.html) into your `sigset_t`. This means that your `sigset_t` is going to contain the set of signals that are currently *blocked* by your process. I assume the default is nothing is blocked, so the set would be empty.

You might want to test this by printing out the contents of the set, or just looking at it in a debugger.

Now from the docs I understand what [`sigdelset(&p_myset, SIGUSR1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigdelset.html) will do is *remove* the signal `SIGUSR1` from the set you just filled. This set is by assumption already empty so it's unlikely this call does anything. Again, verify by looking at it in a debugger.

So now what [`sigsuspend()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigdelset.html) is going to do is replace your process signal mask with your new mask, which by assumption isn't any different than the default mask (again, **check this in a debugger**). Then on the child side will wait until the process receives `SIGUSR1` and processes it via a signal handler. So your child will process `SIGUSR1` but only because that's the default behaviour.

Your example code doesn't seem to have installed any signal handlers. I think you would have to call the [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigaction.html) function to do that. Therefore very likely the default signal handler will run to process `SIGUSR1`.

According to [this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/signal.h.html), the default signal handling for `SIGUSR1` is

> (i) ... Abnormal termination of the process. The process is terminated with all the consequences of _exit() except that the status made available to wait() and waitpid() indicates abnormal termination by the specified signal.

So I'm guessing the child dies when the parent does `kill(child_pid, SIGUSR1)`. This would mean the child isn't around to signal the parent back.

This is mainly guesswork on my part. What I recommend for you is learning how to use `gdb` or some other debugger so you can set some breakpoints and step through and learn what the program is actually doing.

Comment: So my understanding is that sigfillset will add all signals to the set to be blocked. Then deletes the one signal when i use sigdelset. Then for the signal handlers, at the beginning of each of the processes (the if and else, or child and parent processes) I use sigaction and set the handler. I will start working on the gdb, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @user3746000, the first thing I would recommend is debugging your child process. See if it dies when it gets the first signal. If I'm right about that, you should probably accept my answer and then carry on :)

Comment: Yes, this is about right.  W/O the signal handlers registered `sigsuspend` will never return because the default disposition of the SIGUSRs are to terminated the process.  The child dies, the parent hangs waiting for a signal that will never come.  There are other problems too.   Sleep can cover up a timing issue in something simple like this but it is not a solution.

Comment: Both answers were great, thank you for the help. I just had to add the sigaction(SIGUSR1, &c_sig, NULL) statements. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `sigaction` after defining the `struct sigaction` on both the parent and child. Also, beware that the `struct sigaction p_sig` is redefined in the parent process.

So, I guess if you change your program to something like listed below, it should work.

```
--- foo.c   2014-06-16 16:37:10.918932118 -0300
+++ bar.c   2014-06-16 16:37:48.710228467 -0300
@@ -36,10 +36,6 @@
 {
     pid_t child_pid, parent_pid;
     parent_pid = getpid();
-    struct sigaction p_sig;
-    sigemptyset(&p_sig.sa_mask);
-    p_sig.sa_flags = 0;
-    p_sig.sa_handler = p_sig_usr;
     child_pid = fork();
     if ( child_pid == -1){
         perror("failed to fork a new process");
@@ -51,6 +47,7 @@
         sigemptyset(&c_sig.sa_mask);
         c_sig.sa_flags = 0;
         c_sig.sa_handler = c_sig_usr;
+        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &c_sig, NULL);
         child_pid = getpid();
         printf("CHILD %d: Running, parent is %d\n",child_pid, parent_pid);
         sigfillset(&c_myset);
@@ -69,6 +66,10 @@
     }
     else{
         struct sigaction p_sig;
+        sigemptyset(&p_sig.sa_mask);
+        p_sig.sa_flags = 0;
+        p_sig.sa_handler = p_sig_usr;
+        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &p_sig, NULL);
         sigset_t p_myset;
         sigemptyset(&p_myset);
         sleep(3);//parent now sleeping to let child set up handlers
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This is what made it click, I forgot the sigaction(SIGUSR1, &c_sig, NULL)! Thanks again!